# filter history to clean git repo from submodules

Tags: git, bazaar, git-submodules

How can you remove references to submodules in a git repo which no longer uses submodules (merged them) so that bazaar can import it?

> bzr: ERROR: The repository you are fetching from contains submodules, which are not yet supported.

It should be possible according to jelmer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/402814/comments/43

> There is no way to tell the import system to just ignore history. You could provide a custom repository that has the submodules filtered out of the history or filter them out of your history on github.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, see https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/88128/ for an explanation of why.  It looks as if they're trying to get bzr to handle this but aren't there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Importing a repository with submodules is not yet supported. The required support for dealing with submodules *is* present in bzr-git, but the feature that submodules are mapped to, which is called "nested trees" is not yet finished.